# Ionic 3: deployment typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I finished up the app I was working on and it works on ionic serve with no issues, however when compiling I was met with this, any help is much appreciated.

```js
[15:40:08]  typescript error 
            Type ResultPage in C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.ts is part of the declarations of
            2 modules: AppModule in C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/app/app.module.ts and ResultPageModule in
            C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.module.ts! Please consider moving ResultPage in
            C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in
            C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/app/app.module.ts and ResultPageModule in
            C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that
            exports and includes ResultPage in C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.ts then import
            that NgModule in AppModule in C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/app/app.module.ts and ResultPageModule in
            C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/InfoKing/src/pages/result/result.module.ts.
            
            

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\InfoKing\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\InfoKing\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\InfoKing\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Omar\Desktop\InfoKing\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `result.module.ts` and remove `@IonicPage` from the `result.ts` file and run again
hope it works for you

Comment: Worked but I also removed the IonicPage import. Thanks :D

Comment: Glad that it helps